# Extending the Bitmap Class in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, extend

Is there a way to extend the Bitmap class in Android? I have a feeling you can't, but I would like to create a class for a bitmap which represents a falling object ( there will be an indeterminate number of this objects falling from the top of the screen, and each will have to perform some sort of collision detection). Can I extend/implement the bitmap class to create this custom class that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Bitmap` doesn't even know where it should be placed on the screen.

Even before you get into animation, it seems like you need to represent your scene using a few "SceneObject" objects or some other model that can represent objects with coordinates in your scene. Each of these objects would have as an instance variable a `Bitmap`.

Once that step is complete, animating your objects may just be extending your "SceneObject" class with additional functionality.

Your rendering function would interpret your scene and layout bitmaps according to the information in your models.

Comment: That is what I was trying to do. However, whenever I try to do this from my constructor  "Bitmap blossom = 
   (BitmapFactory.decodeResource
     (getResources(), R.drawable.blossom));"   I get an error saying that getResources is undefined for the type Blossom. How can I read in a Bitmap???

Comment: `getResources` is a method on `Context`. If you're in an activity you can use that context.

Comment: So should my "Blossom" class extend Activity? I can't see any other way to instantiate a bitmap in there :/ unless I can read it directly from the file?

Comment: No just hand in the Context via a pointer to the Activity or the value returned by View.getContext().

Answer (score 5):

You can't extend Bitmap, because it is declared `final`. The best you can do is create a class that wraps a Bitmap.